# AngularJS - same timer for all directive instances

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is a best "Angular Way" to implement the directive that will have a shared timer for all it instances?

For example I have a directive "myComponent" and on the page it appears many times.
Inside of the component, exists some text that blink with some interval.

Because of business requirements and performance considerations, I would like that there will be single "timeout" that will toggle the blink for all instances at once (after document is ready).

I thought about the writing some code within directive definition:

```
//Pseudo code
angular.module("app",[]).directive("myComponent", function($timeout){
   $(function() { $timeout(function(){ $(".blink").toggle(); }, 3000); } );
   return {
      //Directive definition
   };
});
```

Or by using some kind of service that will receive the `$element` and add remove class to it:

```
//Pseudo code
angular.module("app",[])
.service("myService", function($timeout){
     var elements = [];

     this.addForBlink = function(element) { elements.push(element) };

     $(function() { $timeout(function(){ $(elements).toggle(); }, 3000); } );
})
.directive("myComponent", function(myService){

   return {
      compile:function($element){
        myService.addForBlink($element);
        return function() { 
           //link function
        }
      }
   };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion the most elegant and efficient would be to combine both these approaches by specifying the logic of the directive in the very directive initialization function. Here is a scaffold of what I actually mean:

```
app.directive('blinking', function($timeout){

    var blinkingElements = [];

    var showAll = function() {
        for(var i = 0; i < blinkingElements.length; i++){
            blinkingElements[i].addClass("blinking");
        }
    };

    var hideAll = function() {
        for(var i = 0; i < blinkingElements.length; i++){
            blinkingElements[i].removeClass("blinking");
        }
    };

    var blink = function () {
        $timeout(showAll, 500);
        $timeout(function(){
            hideAll();
            if (blinkingElements.length > 0) {
                blink();
            }
        }, 1000);
    };

    return {

        link : function(scope, element, attrs){

            blinkingElements.push(element);
            if (blinkingElements.length == 1) {
                blink();
            }

            element.on("$destroy", function(){
                var index = blinkingElements.indexOf(element);
                blinkingElements.splice(index, 1);
            });

        }
    }
});
```

And here is the working <kbd>[demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/hs96DLWxi17SJuVo9bxt?p=preview)</kbd>.

---

Moreover you can inject some `service` that will be responsible for configuration (setting the intervals and / or class) or you can provide the configuration by passing an object directly to the attribute. In the latter case you can enable applying different classes for different elements, but you should think of some policy how to deal with situation, when the interval was set more than once.